# Como saber qual é o PID de um script Python atualmente executado?

Tags: python, processo

Tenho um determinado script Python que desejo saber qual é o PID atual dele, através do próprio script.

Como eu posso fazer isso?

Através disso também, eu posso determinar que ele seja executado somente uma vez?

Comment: Você quer que o próprio script retorne o seu PID ou o script retornar o PID de outro script?

Comment: "Atualmente executado". o próprio script, vou editar :p

Answer (score 4):

Antes de responder, valos falar um pouco sobre **PID**.

> Process identifier (identificador de processo), PID ou ainda process ID é um número único que é atribuído pelo sistema operativo quando um processo é executado. Esse número é utilizado para se fazer referência a um processo que está a executar.

fonte: [wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identificador_de_processo)

Em resumo, cada processo executado no sistema operacional terá o seu próprio **PID**.

Existem algumas formas de se fazer isso, mas a mais simples é apenas importar o `os` e utilizar o método [`getpid()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getpid) para obter o **PID** do processo atual.

Exemplo:

```
import os

pid = os.getpid()
```

Você também pode obter o **PID** com base no nome do processo, e outras formas.

[Veja demais formas nesta pergunta.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3761639/4843158)